# jQuery Mobile Dialog Disappears immediately in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I've looked at this for a while and feel like I'm missing something obvious...

I am using jQuery mobile to popup a dialog for users of a web app, I am using user agent sniffing to provide a quick dialog to direct the user on how to install the app if they choose based on their platform.

While it might not seem to matter, I want to make sure that I cover my bases as well as possible. The last if statement applies to browsers less than 600 pixels wide that doesn't have one of the previous ua strings... so, if you reduce down a desktop install of Chrome it will trigger that pop-up. However, in Chrome it appears and then immediately disappears. I cannot see any errors thrown and since I don't see it happening in Firefox, I'm not seeing what's happening.

I have two questions:

1 - Does anyone know what's happening here? I've tried with and without returning false, which I don't think should matter, but just to test escape.

2 -  Does anyone have a suggestion on doing this cleaner. Since I'm testing the ua, I was considering trying to run this as a switch statement, but I'm not sure if testing that would work correctly... but I feel like I'm not wrapping my head around this the right way.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
var isWinPhone = ua.indexOf("windows phone") > -1;
var isBlackberry = ua.indexOf("blackberry") > -1;
var isbbTen = ua.indexOf("bb10") > -1;
var current_width = $(window).width();
$( '#home' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
if(isAndroid) {
$.mobile.changePage( '#android' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
return false;
};
if(isWinPhone) {
$.mobile.changePage( '#winPhone' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
return false;
};
if(isBlackberry) {
$.mobile.changePage( '#Blackberry' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
return false;
};
if(isbbTen) {
$.mobile.changePage( '#bbTen' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
return false;
};
if(current_width < 599 && !isAndroid && !isWinPhone && !isBlackberry && !isbbTen){
$.mobile.changePage( '#generic' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
return false;
};
});
```

You can see the same thing happen here: http://jsfiddle.net/fskirschbaum/2YTwE/1/ IF you view it in Chrome.

I've tried a few other parameters, but without understanding why it's happening in the first place, I'm at a loss as to where to start.

Comment: What version of JQuery do you run in your environment ? And where is your #dialog page in your jsfiddle example ?

Comment: I've been running jQuery 1.8.3 and I've been running jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 and 1.2.0 - The #dialog page on the same page with the other two pages using multi-page processing for jQuery Mobile, so it's contained in <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you link proper jQuery and jQuery Mobile libs everything works just fine (see jsFiddle at the end).
2. How about this implementation

```js
$('#home').on('pageinit', function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        page = '', 
        role='dialog';

    switch(true) {
        case (ua.indexOf("android") > -1):
            page = '#android';
            break;
        case (ua.indexOf("windows phone") > -1):
            page = '#winPhone';
            break;
        case (ua.indexOf("blackberry") > -1):
            page = '#Blackberry';
            break;
        case (ua.indexOf("bb10") > -1):
            page = '#bbTen'; 
            break;
        case ($(window).width() < 599):
            page = '#generic';
            break;
    }
    if (page.length) {
        $.mobile.changePage(page, {transition:'pop', role:role});
        return false;
    }    
});
```

And here is working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/GmVTM/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like what you did with the switch statement, I was having a little trouble envisioning it.

Answer (score 2):

I too had a disappearing dialog problem - turns out to have been related to earlier attempt to get rid of "flickering" - a SO answer suggested that the following would stop the flickering (it didn't):

```
.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

When I removed this line of css, the dialog worked ok.

Comment: That's for coming back to this one, that's an interesting suggestion. It wasn't the issue in my case, but I did just put together a quick demo using that CSS and saw the problem occur. I have seen that CSS (and a few others to help 'fix transitions' in jQm) referenced before. Perhaps it will be useful to anyone searching for help with this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too, if I had a popup open conditionally on loading the page, in the Chrome browser (not in FF) The fix turned out to be updating the library to jqm 1.3.1.

That's it. Tested in FF and Chrome.

Note that 1.3.0b -- which is available as an option on jsfiddle.com, doesn't work. 1.3.1 does.

Then bind to the pageshow event:

```
jQuery(document).on ( 'pageshow', function(event) {
    $( '#popupID' ).popup('open'); 
});
```